# Set of valid values for expansion

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$f(x)=1+\frac{1}{x-3}-\frac{1}{x+2}$$
Expand this equation up to the term$\frac{1}{x^3}$.

Here's my answer:
$$f(x)=1+\frac{5}{x^2}+\frac{5}{x^3}$$

My question is what is the valid set of values for the expansion?

Using $$|\frac{3}{x}|<1$$
I get the valid set is $$|x|>3$$

(If you try to expand the equation, you will know why I am using $|\frac{3}{x}|<1$.)

However, when substituting the value, it seems like the valid set is not $|x|>3$. I don't know whether I evaluate the wrong answer or this is the nature of the expansion.

Comment: Why do you say "it seems like the valid set is not $|x|>3$" ?

Comment: $\text{However, when substituting the value}$ Which value are you substituting and where?

Comment: Because when I substituted x=3.1 for both equations, there is a huge difference in both values, when I substituted x=100, I get almost the same value. The answer is right, but I think the range has some errors.

Comment: @HolmesQueen, why did you expect that your three term expansion (!) will get you a good approximation so close to the boundary of your convergence interval? There is nothing wrong with 'huge difference' in this case

Comment: So,you mean my set of value is right?

Comment: @Holmes Queen You should write that $f(x)=1+\frac{5}{x^2}+\frac{5}{x^3}+o(1/x^3)$. The diffrence between real value $f(x)$ and the approximate one $1+\frac{5}{x^2}+\frac{5}{x^3}$ goes to zero as $x\to+\infty$. Moreover the full expansion (the one with infinite terms) coincides with $f$ for $|x|>3$.

Comment: $f(z)$ is holomorphic on the open disc (i.e. the disc that does not include its own boundary) centred at the origin and of radius 2, and thus expressible as a Taylor series therein. A disc of larger radius would enclose a singularity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function

\begin{align*}
 f(x)&=1+\frac{1}{x-3}-\frac{1}{x+2}\\
\end{align*}
 has two simple poles at $-2$ and $3$.

> We look at the poles $-2$ and $3$ and see they determine *three* regions.
>
> \begin{align*}
>  |x|<2,\qquad\quad
>  2<|x|<3,\qquad\quad
>  3<|x|
>  \end{align*}
>
> - The first region $ |x|<2$ is a disc with center $0$, radius $2$ and the pole $-2$ at the boundary of the disc. In the *interior* of this disc all two fractions with poles $-2$ and $3$  admit a representation as *Taylor series* at $x=0$.
> - The second region $2<|x|<3$ is the annulus with center $0$, inner radius $2$ and outer radius $3$. Here we have a representation of the fraction with pole $-2$ as principal part of a Laurent series at $x=0$, while the fraction with pole at $3$ admits a representation as power series.
> - The third region $|x|>3$ containing all points outside the disc with center $0$ and radius $3$ admits for all fractions a representation as principal part of a Laurent series at $x=0$.

Since the problem is asking for an expansion up to $\frac{1}{x^3}$ we have to consider the third region and the expansion is according to OP
\begin{align*}
f(x)&=1+\frac{1}{x-3}-\frac{1}{x+2}\\
&=1+\frac{5}{x^2}+\frac{5}{x^3}+\cdots\tag{1}
\end{align*}

*Hint:* It is essential to write at least dots ($\cdots$)  in (1) otherwise the equal sign ($=$) is not correct.